# Make a tab active depending on the day and time of day. JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to duplicate this function on this page.

https://womenimpacttech.com/wit-connect/event

I'm not sure what to search or call this to find documentation on how to do this.

What I'm referring to on that page is 1st when you open the page up there are tabs at the top with labels for the days of the week. Depending on what the current day is, that is the tab that is active. 2nd is the agenda on the left. After it determines which day is suppose to be active it then, depending on the time of day, makes the time slot that is equal to the current time active. So for example, if it is Tuesday then the Tuesday tab is active and then if it is 2:00pm then the tab in the agenda that has 2:00pm within it is active.

Just looking for any help/direction to get it started.

Comment: update your question,  add code you tried.

Comment: Break down the problem; you know you need to associate the tabs with the days, so you'll want to know how to get the current day from JavaScript. There are plenty of questions about that on SO. Then add something to the tab's HTML so that it's easy to select that tab based on the current day. Ditto for the times.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you know jquery very well there is documentation https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp
You can use Date function to take date, year, month, even you can take week day as number just read with carefully,
after that you can write algorithm to make active tab. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The website you're referring seems to be changing the data being rendered based on the 'tabs' that get clicked. They are using [React](https://reactjs.org/) to do this which would make it easier to get the same functionality (or an alternative like [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)), but you can get the same results using jquery (or plain javascript).

The first thing you need is the data to render. Let's assume you have your data which looks something like the following:

```
{
  "days": [
    {
      "date": "2020-06-25",
      "agendaItems": [
        {
          "start": "2020-06-25T17:00:00.000Z",
          "end": "2020-06-25T17:45:00.000Z",
          "type": "Keynote",
          "title": "The title",
          "description": "The description",
          "videoUrl": "https://www.thevideos.com/thisvideo"
        }
        ...
      ]
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

With this data you can loop over the array of days to render the days and also add a onclick event on each day to render its contents based on its data. The same approach can be used to render the agenda items for the selected date.

For rendering today's agenda item of the current time, you can do this while you are rendering the data by checking if today's date and time are within the bounds of any agenda item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps You. Ofcourse You can use tabs instead of divs from my example and then add class to this element instead of "today" mayby "active".

```js
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

for(let i=1;i<=7;i++){
  let g=i;
  if(i==7) g=0;
  let d = new Date();
  let $button = $('#day1').clone();
  $button.css("display","inline-block");
  $button.html(days[g]);
  if(i==d.getDay()){
    $button.addClass("today"); 
  }
  
  $("#result").append($button);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

img {
  width: 56px;
  height: 48px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: 26px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.day{
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}

.today{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="day1" class="day" data-day=1 style="display:none"></div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```